# dynamic controller for flutter

Tags: json, flutter, controller, flutter-dependencies

I have in my code a FutureBuilder that returns data from an API, with this data I create several form fields.
Example of what I map from my API:

```
{
  "id": form.id,
  "label": form.label,
  "required": form.requireed,
  "type": form.type,
  "mask": form.mask,
  "formatting": form.formatting,
  "format": form.format,
  "originalFormat": form.originalFormat,
  "html5Input": form.html5input,
  "codcampodinamico": form.codcampodinamico,
  "fieldSize": form.fieldSize,
  "value": form.value,
  "values": form.values,
}
```

In my "value" field I have to pass what is typed in my TextForm, as I have several, how can I get what is typed in all my fields and associate it with each corresponding field?

Comment: Can you give us some of your code that you tried so far, and we will try to find a solution to your problem